Неправильно отображаются символы кириллицы в richTextBox, Windows Forms, C++
Создаю программу на Windows Forms по взлому шифра Цезаря на C++. В проекте определены два класса: Decrypt и RussianDecrypt, которые возвращают строку std::wstring. Пользователь вводит текст в richTextBox, и по нажатии на кнопку buttonCrack на другие richTextBox выводится расшифрованный текст (для английского и русского языков). При работе с английским языком проблем не возникает, всё работает корректно, но если ввести текст на русском, то при нажатии на кнопку вместо символов кириллицы выводятся непонятные символы.


RussianDecrypt.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class RussianDecrypt {
public:
    static std::wstring CaesarCypherCrack(std::wstring& inputText);

private:
    static double CalculateD(const std::vector<double>& p, const std::vector<double>& f, int s, const std::wstring& alphabet);
};

RussianDecrypt.cpp
#include "RussianDecrypt.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

double RussianDecrypt::CalculateD(const std::vector<double>& p, const std::vector<double>& f, int s, const std::wstring& alphabet)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < alphabet.size(); i++) {
        sum += std::abs(p[i] - f[(i + s) % alphabet.size()]);
    }
    return sum;
}

std::wstring RussianDecrypt::CaesarCypherCrack(std::wstring& inputText)
{
    // Частоты букв в русском языке
    std::vector<double> p = {
    0.07821,  // А
    0.01732,  // Б
    0.04533,  // В
    0.01687,  // Г
    0.02977,  // Д
    0.08398,  // Е
    0.00094,  // Ё
    0.00940,  // Ж
    0.01641,  // З
    0.07367,  // И
    0.01210,  // Й
    0.03486,  // К
    0.04343,  // Л
    0.03203,  // М
    0.06700,  // Н
    0.10983,  // О
    0.02804,  // П
    0.04746,  // Р
    0.05473,  // С
    0.06318,  // Т
    0.02615,  // У
    0.00162,  // Ф
    0.00764,  // Х
    0.00348,  // Ц
    0.01440,  // Ч
    0.00728,  // Ш
    0.00331,  // Щ
    0.00020,  // Ъ
    0.01983,  // Ы
    0.01732,  // Ь
    0.00331,  // Э
    0.00541,  // Ю
    0.01801   // Я
    };

    std::wstring alphabetLower = L"абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
    std::wstring alphabetUpper = L"АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";

    // Подсчитываем частоты в зашифрованном тексте
    std::vector<double> f(alphabetLower.size(), 0);
    int total = 0;

    for (char c : inputText) {
        auto pos = alphabetLower.find(tolower(c));
        if (pos != std::wstring::npos) {
            f[pos]++;
            total++;
        }
    }

    for (double& count : f) {
        count /= total;
    }

    // Поиск минимального D(s)
    int bestShift = 0;
    double minD = CalculateD(p, f, 0, alphabetLower);

    for (int s = 1; s < alphabetLower.size(); s++) {
        double currentD = CalculateD(p, f, s, alphabetLower);
        if (currentD < minD) {
            minD = currentD;
            bestShift = s;
        }
    }

    // Расшифровка с найденным сдвигом
    std::wstring result;
    for (char c : inputText) {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            bool isUpper = isupper(c);
            const std::wstring& alphabet = isUpper ? alphabetUpper : alphabetLower;
            auto pos = alphabet.find(c);
            if (pos != std::wstring::npos) {
                result += alphabet[(pos - bestShift + alphabet.size()) % alphabet.size()];
            }
        }
        else {
            result += c;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

фрагмент кода формы, функция buttonCrack_Click
private: System::Void buttonCrack_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    // Расшифровка шифра на английском
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::wstring stdInputText = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>(inputText);
    std::wstring stdDecryptedText = Decrypt::CaesarCipherCrack(stdInputText);
    System::String^ DecryptedText = gcnew System::String(stdDecryptedText.c_str());
    this->richTextBox2->Text = DecryptedText;

    // Расшифровка шифра на русском
    std::wstring wstdInputText = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>(inputText);
    std::wstring wstdDecryptedText = RussianDecrypt::CaesarCypherCrack(wstdInputText);
    System::String^ russianDecryptedText = gcnew System::String(wstdDecryptedText.c_str());
    this->richTextBox3->Text = russianDecryptedText;
}

Что самое интересное, если в richTextBox3 попробовать просто вывести строку, например, скопировав вводимый текст, то русские символы будут отображаться корректно.
this->richTextBox3->Text = inputText + L" ЭТО КОПИЯ";


Пробовал настроить проект под символы Юникода, но там и так всё правильно.
Изначально использовал std::string, но потом сделал через std::wstring так как он поддерживает символы Юникода, но проблема не решилась.
Также, для вашего удобства прикрепляю ссылку на этот проект на GitHub, чтобы вы могли полностью просмотреть проект.

char заменить на wchar_t
